# Which stream cipher can we replace the RC4 in the SSL?

Tags: stream-cipher, tls, rc4

> In cryptography, the Fluhrer, Mantin and Shamir attack is a particular stream cipher attack, a dedicated form of cryptanalysis for attacking the widely-used stream cipher RC4. The attack allows an attacker to recover the key in an RC4 encrypted stream from a large number of messages in that stream.
>   The Fluhrer, Mantin and Shamir attack applies to specific key derivation methods, but does not apply to RC4-based SSL (TLS), since SSL generates the encryption keys it uses for RC4 by hashing, meaning that different SSL sessions have unrelated keys.

From [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/502.pdf). Does it mean that RC4 is not so secure as we want? And which stream cipher can we replace the RC4 in the SSL?

Comment: Context? Future extensions in SSL? Or as a server operator who's limited to existing implementations?

Comment: AES-CTR and Salsa20/ChaCha are the most popular stream ciphers in my experience.

Comment: Can we use AES-CTR and Salsa20/ChaCha in the TLS? Can we choose it as cipher suit?

Comment: There is AES-GCM (which is based on AES-CTR) in TLS 1.2, and AGL at google works on a ChaCha-Poly1305 suite. But there are no widely implemented streamciphers in TLS for now.

Comment: It would be a good idea to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, RC4 is not as secure as we would love it to be and considered to be a temporary fallback solution against BEAST attacks on TLS 1.0.

I know Google uses RC4 for most of its services, and this is the reason one shouldn't keep gmail opened all the time ;-)

I believe it must be replaced with AES-128-256. And TLS 1.1 supports such modes, we just need to wait until more and more servers/browsers will start to support it.

I would like to see ECDH-RSA2K-AES256-GCM in the near future used widely.

Answer (score 9):

There are several ways to answer your question:

1. You cannot "replace" RC4 in SSL. SSL is a [standard protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) in which any algorithm may be used only if both client and server support it and agree to use it. Thus, *in practice*, you do not get to replace algorithms as you wish, unless you control both client and server code; and even then, it would not longer be "the standard SSL (actually known as TLS)" but a custom variant.
2. If we want to define a TLS variant, then we can define new cipher suites which use a stream cipher distinct from RC4. There are some good candidates for the job, in particular the [eSTREAM portfolio](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/): these algorithms did get a fair share of analysis, and "seem strong". There is no known detectable bias in them, contrary to RC4. They also happen to be substantially faster.
3. Standard TLS now defines [cipher suites with GCM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5288). [GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) is a block cipher mode of operation which builds on a block cipher with 128-bit blocks (usually AES); the block cipher is used in CTR mode, which actually turns it into a stream cipher. So we can say that using GCM-based cipher suites really is replacing RC4 with another "stream cipher".

Note that SSL/TLS ensures not only confidentiality but also integrity; thus, there must be a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) somewhere. When using RC4 for the stream cipher, the MAC is HMAC with a hash function (MD5 or SHA-1). If you replace RC4 with a super-fast stream cipher which does only encryption, then the HMAC may become the bottleneck. GCM uses the block cipher for both encryption and the MAC, so a fast block cipher actually speeds up the whole thing. On modern x86 processors, there is [hardware support for AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) which includes an opcode specially suited for GCM. On smaller architectures, where performance issues are actually much more probable to matter, GCM is not necessarily a good choice ("fast" implementations of the binary field multiplication in GCM use big tables which are not that fast on CPU with a small L1 cache).

Comment: So far there do not seem to be any commonly available implementations of eSTREAM ciphers. Why?

Comment: as per Vulnerabilities  tools RC4 should not be used where possible, wants to know how to fix this?